# How to get a list of all users with a specific permission group in Django

Tags: python, django, dictionary, permissions

I want to get a list of all Django auth user with a specific permission group, something like this:

```
user_dict = {
    'queryset': User.objects.filter(permisson='blogger')
}
```

I cannot find out how to do this. How are the permissions groups saved in the user model?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

If you want to get list of users by permission, look at this variant:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Permission
from django.db.models import Q

perm = Permission.objects.get(codename='blogger')  
users = User.objects.filter(Q(groups__permissions=perm) | Q(user_permissions=perm)).distinct()
```

Comment: I have a basic Model that has this requirement - filter a list of users on a certain object-level permission (django-guardian). What's the best way to do this - on the Model, on a ModelForm or a separate Form?

Comment: I think this query needs a `| Q(is_superuser=True)` ;)

Comment: Slightly better & lazier query - `User.objects.filter(Q(groups__permissions__codename="blogger") | Q(user_permissions__codename="blogger") | Q(is_superuser=True))`

Comment: @marcelm good catch, though there are use cases for which this is not desirable, such as when the list of users fetched is for an action that is opt-in, i.e. shouldn't affect superusers unless they explicitly want to.

Answer (score 47):

This would be the easiest

```
from django.contrib.auth import models

group = models.Group.objects.get(name='blogger')
users = group.user_set.all()
```

Answer (score 19):

I think for group permissions, permissions are stored against groups, and then users have groups linked to them. So you can just resolve the user - groups relation.

e.g.

```
518$ python manage.py shell

(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
>>> User.objects.filter(groups__name='monkeys')
[<User: cms>, <User: dewey>]
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it, i knew should be simple. The only problem is if the group name is changed, maybe i should filter it on ID or something instead...

But thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Based on @Glader's answer, this function wraps it up in a single query, and has been modified to algo get the superusers (as by definition, they have all perms):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models import Q

def users_with_perm(perm_name):
    return User.objects.filter(
        Q(is_superuser=True) |
        Q(user_permissions__codename=perm_name) |
        Q(groups__permissions__codename=perm_name)).distinct()

# Example:
queryset = users_with_perm('blogger')
```

Answer (score 8):

Do not forget that specifying permission codename is not enough because different apps may reuse the same codename. One needs to get permission object to query Users correctly:

```
def get_permission_object(permission_str):
    app_label, codename = permission_str.split('.')
    return Permission.objects.filter(content_type__app_label=app_label, codename=codename).first()

def get_users_with_permission(permission_str, include_su=True):
    permission_obj = get_permission_object(permission_str)
    q = Q(groups__permissions=permission_obj) | Q(user_permissions=permission_obj)
    if include_su:
        q |= Q(is_superuser=True)
    return User.objects.filter(q).distinct()
```

Code with imports:
https://github.com/Dmitri-Sintsov/django-jinja-knockout/blob/master/django_jinja_knockout/models.py

Comment: Best answer. Although note that `content_type__model=model` should also be included.

Answer (score 1):

Groups are many-to-many with Users (you see, nothing unusual, just Django models...), so the answer by cms is right. Plus this works both ways: having a group, you can list all users in it by inspecting `user_set` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
User.objects.filter(groups__permissions = Permission.objects.get(codename='blogger'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Augusto's answer, I did the following with a model manager and using the authtools library. This is in `querysets.py`:

```
from django.db.models import Q
from authtools.models import UserManager as AuthUserManager

class UserManager(AuthUserManager):
    def get_users_with_perm(self, perm_name):
        return self.filter(
                Q(user_permissions__codename=perm_name) |
                Q(groups__permissions__codename=perm_name)).distinct()
```

And then in `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from authtools.models import AbstractEmailUser
from .querysets import UserManager


class User(AbstractEmailUser):
   objects = UserManager()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ python manage.py shell <<'EOF'
> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
> User.objects.filter(groups__name='blogger')
> EOF
...
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> >>> [<User: foo>, <User: bar>, <User: baz>, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']
```

(simplified from cms' answer, which I can't edit)