# How to send_mail to Users in group in Django?

Tags: python, django, email

I would like to send an email to all users with consultant permission: **perms.profiles.consultant_permission**

My code is the following:

**model.py**

```
 class Profile(models.Model):
    //some attributes

    class Meta:
         permissions = (
             ('consultant_permission', 'Consultant Permission'),
         )
```

**view.py**

```
consultant_msg_html = render_to_string('email/consultant_review_email.html', context)
send_mail("Register sent to review", 
    consultant_msg_html, 
    registration.consultant.email, 
    [registration.consultant.email,], 
    html_message=consultant_msg_html, 
    fail_silently = False)
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can override Django default User Model, to make that `Profile` class ([more here](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2013/08/07/migrating-custom-user-model-django/)), you could have an attribute `permissions` for that model, and filter users with consultant permissions, get a list of their e-mails and send the emails (in your views.py).

Comment: I assume your Profile model is already linked to the user account. Have a look here how to grab the user queryset: http://stackoverflow.com/a/992329/640916

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First you need to get all users with the specific permission:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Permission
from django.db.models import Q

perm = Permission.objects.get(codename='consultant_permission')  
users = User.objects.filter(Q(groups__permissions=perm) | Q(user_permissions=perm) ).distinct()
recipients = list(i for i in users.values_list('email', flat=True) if bool(i))
```

Then you can use `recipients` in your [`send_email()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/email/#send-mail).

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome @GustavoReyes!

Comment: Can you explain the line recipients = list(....)? Specifically, what is the `if bool(i)` doing? Is it to avoid adding blank user email addresses?