# How to get all users of a group in Django?

Tags: django

I want to get a list of all users who are within a Django Group. For example:

`User.objects.filter(group='Staff')`

I cannot find how to do this query anywhere in the docs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a list of all users with a specific permission group in Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378303/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-users-with-a-specific-permission-group-in-django)

Comment: I looked that up but I am unable to understand why I have to import `Permission` to query the users of a `Group`. It is too confusing.

Comment: if you look at the second answer, you'll see you don't have to.

Comment: It looks like this `User.objects.filter(group__name='Staff')`. But this example exists in suggested answer in first comment.

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev it should probably be plural like `groups__name` as the relation between user and group models is M2M.

Comment: Yes. That worked! Thanks @SardorbekImomaliev

Answer (score 92, accepted):

The following query solved my problem.

`User.objects.filter(groups__name='Staff')`

Thanks to @SardorbekImomaliev for figuring it out.

Comment: Is there a way to get users while filtering by group id rather than group name?

Comment: @MalachiBazar you could do groups__id if you want to search by group id.

Answer (score 13):

This query allows you to find users by group id rather than by group name:

```
group = Group.objects.get(id=group_id)
users = group.user_set.all()
```

Here's a query that lets you search by group name:

```
users = User.objects.filter(groups_name='group_name')
```

Comment: Just a small edit, one needs to use double underscore 

`users = User.objects.filter(groups__name='group_name')`

Comment: Does the model have to be imported first?